# Capture text after an OR group in Emacs Lisp

Tags: regular-expressions

Say I want to match the `a` character "`h a`" or "`f a`". So capture all the a that are preceded by an `h` or an `f`.

I tried the following :

1) `\(h\|f\) \\(a\\)`

but it doesn't work. the problem appears to be with the the OR group, if I do

2) `h \\(a\\)` the `a` in the string `h a` is captured.

Does anyone know how to fix my first expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a clear difference between the group that is working:

```
\\(...\\)
```

and the group that is not working:

```
\(...\)
```

You need to double your backslashes in the non-working group (and for `\\|` as well).

In elisp backslashes are special to *both* the double-quoted string syntax and the regexp syntax, so when regexps are represented as double-quoted strings you need to double-escape the backslashes which are intended for the regular expression.